# Evergrowing blob

Tags: fauna

A creature the size of a bacteria has awakened and starts eating, it eats it's own bodyweight everyday, and it never gets smaller (Unless it mates). The creature is hermaphrodite but it needs a companion.

It only eats organic materials, it eats it by slowly consume it with it's surface.

It can slide over most surfaces, moves fast in the water. (Speed is relative to it's size)

The companion is another place in space.

The being is fairly dumb, it just keeps eating untill it finds a partner, when it does it merges together and splits 4 way.

The being is aware of it's own existence, and it's species. It will not try and mate with it self after it has splittet.

The being is origined in water on earth.

- How much can the being eat before it is out of food?
- How big would the being be after it is out of food?
- Is it posible for the being to leave the earth ?
- How big would it be before it is unable to eat it's own weight in food, due to surface being too small compared with hours a day and amount of food needs to be eaten?

Comment: For the sake of argument, let's suppose this creature gets big enough to encompass the Earth and it is an organic creature. Will it consume itself because it is 1) "fairly dumb" and 2) an organic food source? Also, can it survive out of water?

Comment: @Frostfyre It will not eat it self, good question. It can survive out of water. (It can survive in space)

Comment: [agar.io](http://agar.io/) for the win. :) WARNING: possibly NSFW players

Comment: Actually the idea was spawned by a novel by Leis, Patrick called "Jaktmarken", but agar.io fuled the flame.

Comment: The surface to volume ratio problem kicks in before you can even see this being without a microscope. That's why singles cells, and in kind, single celled organisms are so small and never large.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- How much can the being eat before it is out of food?

So it looks like you have a very dangerous [slime bacteria](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myxobacteria). Unfortunately, the blob's existence would **not** necessarily lead to mass extinction. Assuming these blobs can starve, they will likely fall into a predator/prey cycle.

[image]

As the population of prey begins to falter, so does the blob's ability to find food. They then begin to die off and the prey population rises again only to repeat the process.

But what if they are [apex predators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apex_predator).

It is possible that, since they eat organic matter, no digestive system could completely dispose of them. Following the next month or so, the blob *eats the eater*, quickly teaching all species to steer clear.

---

- How big would the being be after it is out of food?

Wikipedia ballparks earth's total biomass at **560 billion tons C***. *If* the blobs are able to consume  all life, given a rough estimate of bacterial volume/weight (0.6um3/picogram) lands a rough mass at.

**The volume of the Mediterranean Sea** (I am skeptical about this answer and open to revisions)

---

- Is it possible for this being to leave earth?

**Almost definitely not.** The sheer amount of energy required to lift an object of this magnitude would be *far* out of its capabilities. The only plausible escape of gravity would be partial, meaning it would be trivial to fling small pieces of the blob out of the planet's gravity well provided the blob is intelligent enough to even do that. These projectiles would be unguided and not likely land anywhere suitable to consume or reproduce.

---

- How big would it be before it is unable to eat its own weight in food, due to the surface being too small compared with hours in the day and amount of food needs to be eaten?

This question becomes impossible to answer without knowing many other variables such as the rate of consumption, mean time between food discovery, speed of blob, and specific details about the local ecology. The best bet is to maximize surface area by stretching into a pancake like object for the highest food collection rate.

*C stands for organically bound carbon or carbon being used in a living system.